# Manipulate with data in list - C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list with data:

List of values:

```
01;-minus;01.04.2017 07:00:00;1;
01;-minus;01.04.2017 09:00:00;13;
01;-minus;01.04.2017 10:00:00;73;
01;+plus;01.04.2017 07:00:00;22;
01;+plus;01.04.2017 08:00:00;12;
01;+plus;01.04.2017 09:00:00;12;
01;+plus;01.04.2017 10:00:00;33;
```

Notice that in first three rows data is missing at 08:00:00.
How can I create a new list or zip and merge every row in a way that it should look like this:

Completed list:

```
01;1;22;01.04.2017 07:00:00
01;0;12;01.04.2017 08:00:00
01;13;12;01.04.2017 09:00:00
01;73;33;01.04.2017 10:00:00
```

Comment: you can create class which holds all the 
properties and then do linq groupby on last column and create required output

Comment: Your problem statement makes no sense (to me anyway). I don't know what you're trying to achieve and what you mean by "data is missing at 08:00:00". Can you please be more clear of what these values even mean.

Comment: It is a camera counter for ants. Every time when ant goes outside of his anthill, camera detects minus value increment. When he returns, it gives a plus value increment. So if no ant went outside of his anthill, it is zero value. So that's why the record at 8.00 is missing. Makes sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably have the main list as one variable and then have a function to import the data for the latest day.

In that function, I'd populate a 0 value for each hour of the day, then look through that days actual data overwrite that value whenever you have a matching hour of the day in the list. So, when you are missing data you'll get your consistent hourly output at 0 and if you have data you'll add the correct value.

Then add it to your main list.